# jQuery Mobile Page Load Issue

Tags: jquery

I'm building a mobile web app using jQuery Mobile. I'm facing some very strange issues.

Pages are connected with the standard  tag. Whenever I click on a link, the location in address bar changes and I do get redirected to the new page but in order for the page to render something I need to explicitly refresh it using Cntrl+F5 or click on the refresh browser button. I have tried with FF11 and Chrome. Is this a known issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know exactly what you are experiencing since my expectation was the page ready/load events would fire.  There are a number of ways to solve this, such as:

Firstly you could simply add the following clause in the source page for the link to the target page:

```
rel = "external"
```

This will cause the target page to refresh and fire those page load events that I assume has the javascript code you want to have executed.  However, you may not want to have the page exhibit this behaviour, so...


Another option is to add some script to the source page that will be triggered when the target page becomes active (or 'live'):

```
$( '#YourTargetPageName' ).live( 'pageinit', function(event){
  alert( 'Hello from the TargetPage' );
  $('#SomeInputField').val('Changed text in the target page');
});
```

In the example code above, when you link to the target page it will display a popup alert as well as change the text for the selected input field.

Finally, if you wanted to have the same code executed at the start of any and every page, then you  would add the following script:

```
 $(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
   alert( 'Hello from the beginning of every page' );
 });
```

There are plenty of other options that you can explore in the JQM documentation (to be fair I'm only just scratching the surface, so some might work out better for your purposes):

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Further note that the page loading events might behave differently based on whether you are using employing your pages as multi-page or single-page, especially after the first time the page has been loaded.  For example, the events fire only for me once within the multi-page format, and never again for any return to those multi-page links.  However if I break these out into separate single pages then the events fire every time.  This was not apparent to me in the documentation but perhaps I am missing something here that would explain this better to me.